# Cleanup after thread complete taking long time

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a data structure 'FileEntry', which internally has a vector of 'Buckets', both of these are stored as shared pointers. When my fileentry pointer is destructed, the destructor of Buckets is also called as expected, where all the cleanup is done.

I timed the cleanup operation to do some performance measurement and saw something strange, that my bucket pointer cleanup just took 240 and 202 milliseconds, but my full filenetry cleanup took 1768 milliseconds.

```
Completed cleanup for bucket : sessions 240
Completed cleanup for bucket : logs 202
Completed cleanup for fileentry : 1768
```

I use a boost::thread_group, on which buckets perform their job and once both the buckets are complete filenetry is cleared. The main thread wait for the bucket threads to complete.

Here is the code for both the destructors

```
    FileEntry::~FileEntry()
    {
     Timer timer("Completed cleanup for fileentry");
     this->_buckets.clear();
    }

    Bucket::~Bucket()
    { 
      Timer timer("Completed cleanup for bucket");
      this->_sessions.clear();
      this->_meta_lookup.clear();
      this->_unique_meta.clear();
      this->_writer.reset();
    }
```

What wrong am i doing here? How can i check what is happening in the background?

Comment: Does the cleanup involve any I/O (including closing any files)?

Comment: Oh by the way, if any of those variables is a standard C++ container, then you don't have to do anything as their destructors will do the right thing.

Comment: You say "I timed the cleanup operation to do some performance measurement and saw something strange, that my bucket pointer cleanup just took 240 and 202 milliseconds, but my full filenetry cleanup took 1768 seconds." but the timings don't show units and say 240/202/1768...I am wondering if you meant milliseconds when you said seconds??

Comment: Yes sorry i meant milliseconds, all the numbers are in milliseconds.

Comment: The Bucket cleanup involves closing a file this->_writer.reset(), but the bucket one is fast.

Comment: If `FileEntry::_buckets` is a collection of `Bucket` objects, how many `Bucket` instances are there in the collection? It may take a lot of time simply because there are a lot of `Bucket` objects? (Each of which prints to the output, which is pretty slow).

Comment: There are only 2 buckets, in the _buckets collection.